# how to get this sql query

Tags: sql, postgresql

hello everyone I have a problem for this query, I need to get the rows where the id has the same numbers:

```
id2 |  num
----+------
28  | 6
28  | 104
28  | 106
50  | 6
50  | 104
```

expected result:

```
id2 | num
----+-----
28  | 6
28  | 104
50  | 6
50  | 104
```

result doesn't include `28 106` because there's no `50 106` .

case 2:

```
id2 | num
----+-----
29  | 1
30  | 1
31  | 1
```

expected result:

```
id2 | num
----+-----
29  | 1
30  | 1
31  | 1
```

retrieves all because all the ids have num equal to 1

these numbers are random the condition is that if there are more than two ids they must have the same numbers in column 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to count the occurrences of each `num` value, and compare it with the number of `DISTINCT id2` values. If they are the same, then that `num` value occurs for every `id2` value. You can then `SELECT` rows from the table which match those `num` values:

```
SELECT *
FROM data
WHERE num IN (SELECT num
              FROM data
              GROUP BY num
              HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id2) FROM data))
ORDER BY id2, num
```

Output (for first dataset):

```
id2     num
28      6
28      104
50      6
50      104
```

Output (for second dataset):

```
id2     num
29      1
30      1
31      1
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/3956e6/7)

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use an `OVER` clause to count the occurrences of each value in `num` and compare to count of distinct values in `id2` - which can be laterally joined:

> ```
> CREATE TABLE mytable(
>    id2 VARCHAR(11) 
>   ,num INTEGER 
> );
> INSERT INTO mytable(id2,num) VALUES ('28',6);
> INSERT INTO mytable(id2,num) VALUES ('28',104);
> INSERT INTO mytable(id2,num) VALUES ('28',106);
> INSERT INTO mytable(id2,num) VALUES ('50',6);
> INSERT INTO mytable(id2,num) VALUES ('50',104);
>
>
> select id2, num
> from (
>     select
>            id2, num
>          , count(*) over(partition by num) c_num
>          , ca.c_id2
>     from mytable
>     left join lateral (select count(distinct id2) c_id2 from mytable) ca on true
>     ) d
> where c_num = c_id2
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> id2 | num
> :-- | --:
> 28  |   6
> 50  |   6
> 28  | 104
> 50  | 104
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE mytable(
>    id2 VARCHAR(11) 
>   ,num INTEGER 
> );
> INSERT INTO mytable(id2,num) VALUES ('29',1);
> INSERT INTO mytable(id2,num) VALUES ('30',1);
> INSERT INTO mytable(id2,num) VALUES ('31',1);
> ```

> ```
> select id2, num
> from (
>     select
>            id2, num
>          , count(*) over(partition by num) c_num
>          , ca.c_id2
>     from mytable
>     left join lateral (select count(distinct id2) c_id2 from mytable) ca on true
>     ) d
> where c_num = c_id2
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> id2 | num
> :-- | --:
> 29  |   1
> 30  |   1
> 31  |   1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=070dccdb30370df01c503af5969b14df)*

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you want to count the number of distinct `id2` values in the data and the number of distinct `id2` values on each `num`.  If only Postgres supported `count(distinct)` as a window function, you could do:

```
select id2, num
from (select t.*,
             count(distinct t.id2) over (partition by t.num) as cnt_id2_on_num, 
             count(distinct t.id2) over () as cnt_id2
      from t
     ) t
where cnt_id2_on_num = cnt_id2;
```

There is a simple work-around, which is the sum of `dense_rank()`s:

```
select id2, num
from (select t.*,
             (dense_rank() over (partition by t.num order by t.id2) +
              dense_rank() over (partition by t.num order by t.id2 desc)
             ) as cnt_id2_on_num, 
             (dense_rank() over (order by t.id2) +
              dense_rank() over (order by t.id2 desc)
             ) as cnt_id2
      from mytable t
     ) d
where cnt_id2_on_num = cnt_id2;
```

If you know there are no duplicates, you can write this as:

```
select id2, num
from (select t.*,
             count(*) (partition by t.num) as cnt_id2_on_num, 
             (dense_rank() over (order by t.id2) +
              dense_rank() over (order by t.id2 desc)
             ) as cnt_id2
      from mytable t
     ) d
where cnt_id2_on_num = cnt_id2;
```